# ServiceStack.Text NuGet Package for version 3.9.61 and above has the wrong .NET 3.5 dll

Tags: servicestack, nuget, nuget-package, servicestack-text

This is not really a question but...

It seems since 3.9.61 the version of ServiceStack.Text.dll supplied in the NuGet is 3.9.59

Nuget package for ServiceStack.Text 3.9.60 had the correct version as stated but since then the nuget package has included an earlier version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had a look, there was a problem with the MSBuild task that was rewriting the Assembly Version. The dll published was the latest version, unfortunately its reporting an older version.

We'll push out a new release this weekend with the right version.

Comment: Did you ever get around to pushing this new version? I'm also facing this problem :/